# Find indices not in indices vector

Tags: c++, loops, stdvector

How to find indices not in indices in an array? For eg. if indices vector is `(2, 8, 6, 9)`. Then the result should be `(1,3,4,5,7)`. R have a function `(not) %in%` for doing this.  A naive way would be to create an array of flags. But creation of flag and iteration over the non-indices will be two different loops. Is there a way to do this in a single loop?

Comment: Is the maximum known?

Comment: I do not understand this question.  Perhaps you could explain better with code?

Comment: You should be able to use `std::set_difference()` from `<algorithm>`

Comment: If you start indexig from 1, you are holding it wrong.

Comment: Is the minimum known?

Comment: Are the indices guaranteed to be in sorted order and unique?

Comment: They are unique and not sorted. Sorting will make O(nlog(n)). Maximum is known.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
int j = 0;
for(int i = 0;; ++i) {
  if(oldvec[j] == i) {
    j++;
    if(j >= oldvec.length())
      break;
  } else {
    newvec.push_back[i];
  }
}
```

New answer:

```
  std::set<int> result;
  int max = -1;
  for(unsigned int i=0; i<oldvec.size(); ++i)
  {
    int cur = oldvec[i];
    while(max < cur) {
      max++;
      result.insert(max);
    }
    result.erase(cur);
  }
```

How about that? :)
Wait, does the result have to be a std::vector?

Comment: This will fail if `oldvec` is not sorted.

Comment: True, I assumed it was sorted but the example isn't. Good point.

Comment: So: sort that thing and it will be the answer

Comment: @DieterLücking That doesn't really count as one loop imho. :)

Comment: @DieterLücking sorting will make in O(nlog(n)). :)

Answer (score 0):

Sort first and check from `first` to `last` numbers in your "universe" later. Check this function. According to your example, the input would be `A = [2, 8, 6, 9]`, `first = 1`, `last = 9`. You get the solution in `out`. Note that the function modifies `A` to sort it.

```cpp
void getComplement(std::vector<unsigned int> &A, 
  size_t first, size_t last, std::vector<unsigned int> &out)
{
  out.clear();
  if(last < first) return;

  const size_t T = last - first + 1;
  if((int)T - (int)A.size() > 0) out.reserve(T - A.size());

  if(A.empty())
  {
    for(size_t k = first; k <= last; ++k) out.push_back(k);
  }
  else
  {
    std::sort(A.begin(), A.end());

    std::vector<unsigned int>::const_iterator ait = A.begin();

    // elements before the first element of A
    for(size_t k = first; k < *ait; ++k) out.push_back(k);

    // middle elements
    std::vector<unsigned int>::const_iterator bit = ait + 1;
    for(; bit != A.end() ; ++ait, ++bit)
    {
      for(size_t k = *ait + 1; k < *bit; ++k) out.push_back(k);
    }

    // elements after the last element of A
    for(size_t k = A.back() + 1; k <= last; ++k) out.push_back(k);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without sorting:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct NaturalNumber {
    unsigned value;
    bool valid;

    NaturalNumber(unsigned value = 0)
    :   value(value), valid(true)
    {}
};

typedef std::vector<NaturalNumber> NaturalNumbers;

NaturalNumbers natural_number_range(unsigned n) {
    NaturalNumbers result;
    result.resize(n);
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < n; ++i) result[i] = i;
    return result;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    NaturalNumbers n0 = { 2, 8, 6, 9 };
    NaturalNumbers n1 = natural_number_range(10);
    for(NaturalNumbers::const_iterator pos = n0.begin(); pos != n0.end(); ++pos) {
        n1[pos->value].valid = false;
    }
    for(NaturalNumbers::const_iterator pos = n1.begin(); pos != n1.end(); ++pos) {
        if(pos->valid)
            std::cout << pos->value << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It just delegates the sorting to a flag in expense of storing invalid data. There is no single loop, also!